# Facebook Canvas App Authentication/Re-Direct Issues

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-graph-api, canvas

I'm creating a Facebook canvas app, and while the authentication appears to work correctly on the main app view page (loads from http://app.mycanvasurl.com), when I try and add other pages within the app, it doesn't work (for some reason the access token is not returned correctly, so the page returns and OAuth exception [null access token] and re-directs back to the main app page).

As of right now, I am referencing the URLs relatively (a href="/directory/") but I have also tried an absolute (http://apps.facebook.com/my-app/directory/) which DOES work when you navigate to that URL in your browser, but when you click on a link in the app, nothing happens (I'm assuming this is because it's in an iframe, but even trying to set top.location.href onclick does not work to change the state).

Here is my authentication class I built (the main method anyway)

```
function __construct() {

        $this->API = new Network(false);
        $this->DB = new Database();

        session_start();
        $this->code = $_REQUEST['code'];

        if (empty($this->code)) $this->doAuth();                                                            // Authorize User & Create New Session Access Token

        if ($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state'] || 1==1) {                                             // Everything is alright, go ahead and grab the User object

            $tokens = array('{APP_ID}','{APP_URL}','{APP_SECRET}','{REQ_CODE}');
            $tokenReplacements = array(self::$APP['id'], self::$APP['url'], self::$APP['secret'], $this->code);

            parse_str($this->APIRequest('access_token', $tokens, $tokenReplacements, false), $responseParams);

            $this->accessToken = $responseParams['access_token'];

            $this->User = $this->APIRequest('graph_me', array('{ACCESS_TOKEN}'), array($this->accessToken));

            if (is_object($this->User)) {
                $found = $this->DB->fetch('SELECT * FROM user WHERE `fb_id` = "'.$this->User->username.'"');
                if (!$found) $this->addUser();
            }

        }

    }


    protected function APIRequest($url, Array $tokens, Array $replacements, $decode = true) {
        $this->API = (is_object($this->API) && get_class($this->API) == 'Network') ? $this->API : new Network(false);
        if (self::$URL[$url] && count($tokens) == count($replacements)) {
            $requestURL = str_replace($tokens, $replacements, self::$URL[$url]);
            $this->API->newConn($requestURL);
            return ($decode == true) ? json_decode($this->API->Execute()) : $this->API->Execute();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected function doAuth() {
        $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),TRUE));       // CSRF Protection
        $oauthURL = str_replace(array('{APP_ID}','{APP_URL}','{SESS_STATE}'), array(self::$APP['id'], urlencode(self::$APP['url']), $_SESSION['state']), self::$URL['oauth']);
        die('<script>top.location.href="'.$oauthURL.'"</script>');
    }
```

**One more thing: If you notice in the constructor, there is a 1==1 to override the conditional CSRF protection check.  This is because removing it causes the app to enter an infinite re-direct loop (for some reason these values never match up, and I cannot figure out why)**